# On the space of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

There is a problem in Conway functions of one complex variable page 155# 11
Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence in $H(G)$, $f$ is a nonconstant, and $f_n$ converges to $f \in H(G)$. Let $a \in G$ and $\alpha=f(a)$; show that there is a sequence $a_n \in G$ such that

1. $a_n$ converges to $a$
2. $f_n(a_n)=\alpha$ for sufficiently large $n$

(Sorry, I did not write formally but if you understand it, please give me a hint on this problem.)

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for tips on making your equations more readable.

Comment: What do you mean $f_n$ converges to $f$? In what sense?

Comment: The convergence is in the space of holomorphic (analytic)  functions.

Comment: Use [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz's_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29).

Comment: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that for $n > N$ : $g_n(z) = f_n(z)-f(a)$ has a zero on $|z-a|< \epsilon$. Do you know the maximum modulus principle ? $|g(z)|$ has a minimum at $z=a$ therefore for $n$ large enough $|g_n(z)|$ has a minimum close to $z=a$, which must be a zero by the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: An even more direct proof is to assume the opposite, taking a subsequence $g_k = f_{n_k}$ such that $\frac{1}{g_k(z)-f(a)}$ is holomorphic and converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)}$ on $|z-a| < \epsilon$. Of course this is impossible since $\frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)}$ has a pole at $z=a$.

Comment: Good but how is the existence of such subsequence is guaranteed?